# Repeating the consonant in many words in a sentence or phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, rhetorical-devices

In the movie 'V for Vendetta' you have for example (bold part):

> **Evey**: Who are you?
>
> **V.** : Who? Who is but the form following the function of what and what I am is a man in a mask.
>
> **Evey**: Well I can see that.
>
> **V.** : Of course you can, I’m not questioning your powers of observation, I’m merely remarking upon the paradox of asking a masked man who he is.
>
> **Evey**: Oh, right.
>
> **V.** : But on this most auspicious of nights, permit me then, in lieu of the more commonplace soubriquet, to suggest the character of this dramatis persona.
>
> **V.** : Voila!
>   In **view** humble **vaudevillian veteran, cast vicariously as both victim and villain by the vicissitudes of fate. This visage, no mere veneer of vanity, is a vestige of
>   the “vox populi” now vacant, vanished. However, this valorous visitation of a bygone vexation stands vivified, and has vowed to vanquish these venal and virulent vermin, van guarding vice and vouchsafing the violently vicious and voracious violation of volition. The only verdict is vengeance; a vendetta, held as a votive not in vain, for the value and veracity of such shall one day vindicate the vigilant and the virtuous. Verily this vichyssoise of verbiage veers most verbose, so let me simply add that it’s my very good
>   honour to meet you and you may call me V.**
>
> **Evey**: Are you like a crazy person?
>
> **V.** : I’m quite sure they will say so.

What do you call sentences like these?
And do you know some other ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technique itself is called *alliteration*. I'm not sure what I would call an alliterative sentence other than, well, an alliterative sentence. Wikipedia has [an article on alliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration), listing quite a few examples (and mentioning *V for Vendetta*).

Comment: Actually, I think it should be called V literation.  Or at least V iteration.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with RegDwight that it's alliteration, surely, but I would put it down more as a verbal tour de force, similar to Cyrano de Bergerac's coruscation of repartee in Rostand's play of the same name. When he is insulted by an oaf, who tells him he has a big nose, he responds with a speech that purports to be an 'assistance' to the oaf but is at once a profound mockery and a demonstration of how much better a verbal duelist Cyrano is:

> Ah, no, young man, that is not enough!
>   You might have said, dear me, there
>   are a thousand things ... varying the
>   tone ... For instance ... Here you
>   are: — Aggressive: "I, monsieur, if I
>   had such a nose, nothing would serve
>   but I must cut it off!" Amicable: "It
>   must be in your way while drinking;
>   you ought to have a special beaker
>   made!" Descriptive: "It is a crag! ...
>   a peak! ... a promontory! ... A
>   promontory, did I say? ... It is a
>   peninsula!" Inquisitive: "What may the
>   office be of that oblong receptacle?
>   Is it an inkhorn or a scissor-case?"
>   Mincing: "Do you so dote on birds, you
>   have, fond as a father, been at pains
>   to fit the little darlings with a
>   roost?" Blunt: "Tell me, monsieur,
>   you, when you smoke, is it possible
>   you blow the vapor through your nose
>   without a neighbor crying "The chimney
>   is afire!"?" Anxious: "Go with
>   caution, I beseech, lest your head,
>   dragged over by that weight, should
>   drag you over!" Tender: "Have a little
>   sun-shade made for it! It might get
>   freckled!" Learned: "None but the
>   beast, monsieur, mentioned by
>   Aristophanes, the
>   hippocampelephantocamelos, can have
>   borne beneath his forehead so much
>   cartilage and bone!" Off-Hand: "What,
>   comrade, is that sort of peg in style?
>   Capital to hang one's hat upon!"
>   Emphatic: No wind can hope, O lordly
>   nose, to give the whole of you a cold,
>   but the Nor-Wester!" Dramatic: "It is
>   the Red Sea when it bleeds!" Admiring:
>   "What a sign for a perfumer's shop!"
>   Lyric: "Art thou a Triton, and is that
>   thy conch?" Simple: "A monument! When
>   is admission free?" Deferent: "Suffer,
>   monsieur, that I should pay you my
>   respects: That is what I call
>   possessing a house of your own!"
>   Rustic: "Hi, boys! Call that a nose?
>   You don't gull me! It's either a prize
>   parrot or a stunted gourd!" Military:
>   "Level against the cavalry!"
>   Practical: "Will you put up for
>   raffle? Indubitably, sir, it will be
>   the feature of the game!" And finally
>   in parody of weeping Pyramus: "Behold,
>   behold the nose that traitorously
>   destroyed the beauty of its master!
>   and is blushing for the same!" — That,
>   my dear sir, or something not unlike,
>   is what you could have said to me, had
>   you the smallest leaven of letters or
>   wit; but of wit, O most pitiable of
>   objects made by God, you never had a
>   rudiment, and of letters, you have
>   just those that are needed to spell
>   "fool!" — But, had it been otherwise,
>   and had you been possessed of the
>   fertile fancy requisite to shower upon
>   me, here, in this noble company, that
>   volley of sprightly pleasentries,
>   still should you not have delivered
>   yourself of so much as a quarter of
>   the tenth part of the beginning of the
>   first ... For I let off these good
>   things at myself, and with sufficient
>   zest, but do not suffer another to let
>   them off at me!"

For the character of V, I feel the alliteration is not the object of the exercise, it is merely the vehicle. He is intent on displaying verbal prowess to mock, to bait, and to show how much smarter he is than his opponent.

Comment: Good point and a nice quote. +1.

Comment: As such it's an example of [constrained writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing) both for the writer of the piece, and within the narrative, for the character.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of sentences here.

(1) In view humble vaudevillian veteran, cast vicariously as both victim and villain by the vicissitudes of fate.

This is a fragmentary sentence.  Consider "A humble vaudevillian veteran, cast vicariously as both victim and villain by the vicissitudes of fate" ... and what? The whole verb phrase is missing. This is poetic language. To my knowledge there is not a specific word for this.

(2) This visage, no mere veneer of vanity, is a vestige of the “vox populi” now vacant, vanished.

"This dog, no mere poodle, is a an example of the "poodle" breed, (which is) now vanished." There's nothing particularly odd about that one.

(3) However, this valorous visitation of a bygone vexation stands vivified, and has vowed to vanquish these venal and virulent vermin, van guarding vice and vouchsafing the violently vicious and voracious violation of volition.

"However, this poodle has vowed to defeat the cats, (who) are at the forefront of vice and (graciously allow?) the oppression of those who make their own choices."

Nothing syntactically odd here.

(4)  The only verdict is vengeance;

Normal.

(5) a vendetta, held as a votive not in vain, for the value and veracity of such shall one day vindicate the vigilant and the virtuous.

Another fragment. There isn't a top level verb phrase here. "A poodle, doing doggy things, for doggy things are useful and ought to be done as often as possible."

That's not to say that there's anything wrong with these sentences.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was not what the asker had in mind.

Comment: What did they have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a new one:

> Boom!! Behold, a public bulletin board, built of both brilliance and
>   barbarity by bastards with boners. This bastion, no mere bulwark of
>   boredom, is a brutal barrage of blistering bullshit, barely
>   benevolent... but behind the bigotry and boobs, beyond the bitter
>   broadcasts of bragging buffoons: here be the body politic. A
>   brotherhood of blasphemy, blessed with more balls than brains,
>   battling the bland, the bogus, the benign. Bedlam? Bring it on! But I
>   babble... better to be brief. We are 'B'.

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Comment: Ah, B literation!!  I'll note, however, that no one has included any actual examples of A literation yet.